# react map method - put callback function separately and send arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The map method takes a callback function as I've understood it.
Normally you would put the function inside map:

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={todo.id}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

But in my project I call the function as a separate component:

```
{ tabs.map( myFunction ) }
```

here is the myFunction component:

```
const myFunction = (item) => {

    return(

        <Thing 
            key={item.value}
            label={item.label}
            value={item.value} 
        />
    );
}
```

The "item" from map seems to be passed automatically.

The problem is that I need to pass an extra variable - how do I do it? 
This doesn't work:

```
{ tabs.map( myFunction(myvariable) ) }
```

nor:

```
{ tabs.map((styles) => myFunction ) }
```

So I'm unsure how to pass the variable..and still get the "item" passed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
{ tabs.map((tab) => myFunction(tab, myvariable)) }
```

Also note that

```
const myFunction = (item) => {

    return(

        <Thing 
            key={item.value}
            label={item.label}
            value={item.value} 
        />
    );
}
```

could be refactored into

```
const myFunction = (item) => (
        <Thing 
            key={item.value}
            label={item.label}
            value={item.value} 
        />
);
```